# Find the class of the clicked item using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have the following code:

```
    $(".perf-row").click(function(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") {
        pageTracker._trackPageview($(this).attr("rel"));
        return true; //link clicked
      } else {
        window.open($(this).attr("rel"));return false;
      }
    });
```

to the conditional statment of `if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a")` i would like to also add "OR class is equal to price".

I'm not quite sure how to do that, i can't seem to find the class of the clicked element (which will be a td inside the table row).

i've tried `$(this).class`, `$(this.class)` but neither work....

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine both your tests into a single jQuery command:

```
if( $(e.target).is('.price, a') ) { .... }
```

That tests if the target is either has the class `price`, or is an `a` tag, or is both. If you wanted to test that it was an `a` tag *and* had the `price` class, you would use this:

```
if( $(e.target).is('a.price') ) { .... }
```

**Update:** I may have misread your question. If you were going to add this second test to the same `if` test, then use my code. If you wanted to add a `else if` then use the `.hasClass` method as explained by the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

To see whether the element has class `.price`, use the `$.hasClass()` method.

```
$(this).hasClass("price");
```

Comment: No dot prefix is needed here.

Comment: You're right, Joel. I was thinking in terms of selectors. Updated :)

Answer (score -2):

you can try:

```
$(this).attr("class");
```

but this will return you names of all the classes applied to the element.

Comment: Since jQuery has a method for testing class, this is just an incorrect answer, though it does return the classes.